# display a numeric mat as dataset (with Row/Col Names) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, dataset, publish

I'm not very familiar with datasets / displaying data in a readable format in Matlab.  I have a numeric matrix with say 4 cols and I need to display it as:

```
mydata1 = [100 200 400 40] ;
mydata2 = [1   2   3   4 ] ;
display it as -->

         CovA   CovB   CovC  CovD
  Sys1   100    200    400   40
  Sys2   1      2      3     4
```

I am guessing datasets would help me implement this.  Once converted, I'm hoping to publish this dataset with others.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will display a matrix as a table in matlab

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27384-disptable-display-matrix-with-column-or-row-labels

Answer (score 1):

[DATASET](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.html) constructs data column-wise. Consequently, you can either accept that everything is transposed, i.e.

```
ds = dataset({mydata1','sys1'},{mydata2','sys2'},'obsNames',...
     {'CovA','CovB','CovC','CovD'})

ds = 

            sys1    sys2
    CovA    100     1   
    CovB    200     2   
    CovC    400     3   
    CovD     40     4
```

or you construct the dataset rather inconveniently by first catenating `mydata`:

```
mm = [mydata1;mydata2];
dataset(mm(:,1),mm(:,2),mm(:,3),mm(:,4),'varNames',...
       {'CovA','CovB','CovC','CovD'},'obsNames',{'sys1','sys2'})

ans = 

            CovA    CovB    CovC    CovD
    sys1    100     200     400     40  
    sys2      1       2       3      4
```